# Using parenthesis or not when defining a python class

Tags: python, class

When do I need to define a class as this:

```
class test:
```

as opposed to this:

```
class test():
```

In other words, what difference does it make whether or not there is a parenthesis?

Comment: Are you sure you can define class as your second one in Python?

Comment: I am actually not. That answers my question. Sorry for my silly question. I should have just cheked myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "class test():" is used when subclassing it, else if inheritence is not employed, use "class test:"

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses after a class definition are used to indicate inheritance. If you dont inherent it from any other classes. Just simply declare it without parentheses. Look at [this](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) for more information.